# C# regex extract string enclosed into single quotes

Tags: c#, regex, split

I've the following string that I need to parse using RegEx.

```
abc = 'def' and size = '1 x(3\" x 5\")' and (name='Sam O\'neal')
```

This is an SQL filter, which I'd like to split into tokens using the following separators:

```
(, ), >,<,=, whitespace, <=, >=, !=
```

After the string is parsed, I'd like the output to be:

```
abc,
=,
def,
and,
size,
=,
'1 up(3\" x 5\")',
and,
(,
Sam O\'neal,
),
```

I've tried the following code:

```
string pattern = @"(<=|>=|!=|=|>|<|\)|\(|\s+)";
var tokens = new List<string>(Regex.Split(filter, pattern));
tokens.RemoveAll(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
```

I'm not sure how to keep the string in single quotes as a one token. I'm new to Regex and would appreciate any help.

Comment: After `(` add `'[^']*'|`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew - I tried your suggestion with the following pattern: 'string pattern = @"(<=|>=|!=|=|>|<|\)|\(|'[^']*'|\s+)";'. While the string literal '1 up(3\" x 5")' shows up as one token. But the literal 'Sam O\'neal' shows up as two tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern needs an update with yet another alternative branch: `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'`.

It will match:

- `'` - a single quote
- `[^'\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `'` and `\`
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group matching sequences of:

  - `\\.` - any escape sequence
  - `[^'\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `'` and `\`
- `)*` - zero or more occurrences
- `'` - a single quote

In C#:

```
string pattern = @"('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|<=|>=|!=|=|>|<|\)|\(|\s+)";
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%27%5b%5e%27%5c%5c%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%27%5c%5c%5d*%29*%27%7c%3c%3d%7c%3e%3d%7c!%3d%7c%3d%7c%3e%7c%3c%7c%5c%29%7c%5c%28%7c%5cs%2b%29&i=abc+%3d+%27def%27+and+size+%3d+%271+x%283%5c%22+x+5%5c%22%29%27+and+%28name%3d%27Sam+O%5c%27neal%27%29)

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/9XOh3k):

```
var filter = @"abc = 'def' and size = '1 x(3"" x 5"")' and (name='Sam O\'neal')";
var pattern = @"('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|<=|>=|!=|=|>|<|\)|\(|\s+)";
var tokens = Regex.Split(filter, pattern).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
foreach (var tok in tokens)
    Console.WriteLine(tok);
```

Output:

```
abc
=
'def'
and
size
=
'1 x(3" x 5")'
and
(
name
=
'Sam O\'neal'
)
```

Comment: Your code works as provided, but if I change the string to: `string filter = "abc = 'def' and size = '1 x(3\" x 5\")' and (name='Sam O'neal')";
`. "Sam O neal" still breaks into separate tokens, I'll be reading the variable from user input.

Comment: Anyway I've used your previous answer and then handled the apostrophe string by replacing the escaped single quote in "Sam O\'neal" with a special character before RegEx.Split() and then put it back later.

Comment: @AllisonThomas `name='Sam O'neal'` is not possible to match without assumptions. Most probably, it is caused by poor design or is an error.

Comment: @AllisonThomas:  If you managed to work out a solution based on my answer, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribizew, your help is much appreciated. I accepted your answer.